# RPC call in rabbitMQ consumer, how to listen to both queues?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have what seems to be a design issue in my rabbitMQ implementation.

I have a consumer that listens to a queue in order to perform a job that requires multiple sub tasks to be achieved.
Once the job is fully completed, i need to publish a message to a notification queue saying that the job's been completed.

My current WIP is leaning towards that Job worker listening to his queue and publishing RPC messages to specialized workers. 
I want him to listen to RPC responses until everyone is done , before he can publish back to the notification queue.

The problem in this implementation is that i need to listen both to the Job queue (to receive incoming jobs) and the RPC queue (in order to receive replies from each specialized worker).

Apparently this can't be achieved through the consume() method on both queues.

Is my design flawed? (i guess it is) How can i implement this in a "good design" way ?

Thank you

Comment: I actually thought about using the getMessage() method to pull incoming messages from the job queue and consume() from the reply queue, but this really seems like a poor hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [php-amqp](http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp) PHP extension it is not possible. Try to use [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) PHP library instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up but we have already implemented rabbitMq using the php-amqp extension for other type of taks, and i don't want to have both libraries running in the same app, or have to change all the work that was already done. Is there a "design" solution for my issue ? Aside from removing entierly the RPC logic ?

Comment: You can always use second `consume()` to get response, or use `basic.get` in a cycle (not effective in terms of resource usage).

Comment: i thought of that (see my comment on the question) but basically, since i cannot stop consume(), i'm going to "lock" the worker into listening to a rpc queue even when there is no more message to listen to. Of all evil i chose what seemed to be the least , i'm using basic.get on both queues. I'll send that to test bench and see how it goes. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: This is still a valid answer, so props to you for it :)